# Jquery flot bar width automatically becomes wider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bar-chart, flot

I am showing 2 bars side by side using jQuery flot library.
I have set a barWidth, and it renders perfectly fine.

Problem - When one of the bar's value is 0, the bar does not show. But the other bar becomes wider.

Question - how to set the width, and let it be that in any case? I have read on min, max but could not figure out how to use them.

Please see my code below -

```
var myData = [{
        data: plotpoints2,
        color: "red",
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.9,
            fillColor: "red",
            align: "center",
            order: 1
        }
    }, {
        data: plotpoints2,
        color: "green",
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.9,
            fillColor: green,
            align: "center",
            order: 2

        }
    }];
```

Comment: can it is possible to create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code base is quite big to repro in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle to play:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/eb4jtea4/2/
```

to better understand your question, did you mean with bar value the param "barWidth" ? In my example ive set the barwidth of the second to the value "0" and its still shown.

```
$(function () {

var plotpoints2 = [[1, 450], [2, 40], [3, 80], [4, 160], [5, 159], [6, 370], [7, 330], [8, 350], [9, 370], [10, 400], [11, 330], [12, 350]];
    var myData = [{
        data: plotpoints2,
        color: "red",
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.6,
            fillColor: "red",
            align: "center",
            order: 1
        }
    }, {
        data: plotpoints2,
        color: "green",
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0,
            fillColor: "green",
            align: "center",
            order: 2
        }
    }];

    $.plot($("#placeholder"),myData);
});
```